# 9 Speed Cassette does not go all the way in on the free-hub body

Tags: cassette, freehub

Wheel: Shimano WH-R500
Cassette: Shimano CS-HG400-9 9 Speed

I can put the cassette on the free-hub body but the chain will stuck on the highest gear. The cassette seems to not go all the way in on the free-hub body, see the gap between the spokes and cassette.

What did I wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it would be a free hub.  Try rotating.

Comment: Are you able to secure the retaining nut? is the cassette tight when you do or does it float back and forth on the hub? The space between the cassette and the spokes doesn't look that wide, probably just wide enough to put in one of those plastic spoke-guardy things.

Comment: Yes, I can put the nut on and it was screwed quite tight, but the cassette did not move further in.

Comment: does the cassette slide left/right on that hub or is it tight? If it's tight, I would say that it's where it is supposed to be. The extra room is for the plastic chain/wheel guard which you don't need if you set your derailer's high limit screw correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the cassette sprockets fit on the free-hub body and you can install and tighten the lockring then all should be good.

You should be able to see from the non drive side that the cassette spider is sitting at the base of the free-hub body grooves.

Note that some cassettes come with a spacer ring that sits behind the cassette spider.

Comment: My experience has been that if the locking nut fits, it's on correctly unless you forgot one of the cogs

Comment: You were right, everything was good.
I removed the cassette and put it back again, nothing has changed. But this time the chain was not rubbing on the frame. Probably the wheel was not correct installed or the derailleur was somehow pushing the chain against the frame.